# Method call: Method format(java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.thymeleaf.expression.Dates

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem when to use want to java8time expressions in thymeleaf.
When I use #dates.format I have this error:

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method format(java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.thymeleaf.expression.Dates

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2"  th:each="t:${horaire.terrains}">
    <h2 th:text="${t.nomTerrain}"></h2>
    <table border="1px">

        <tr  th:each="h,index : ${heures.subList(0,15)}"   >

            <td>
                <p th:text="${#dates.format(date,'dd-MM-yyyy')}">

                </p>

            </td>
            <td>





                <a th:text="${h}" th:href="@{addResa(heure=${h} , terrain=${t.id} ,date=${date},date2=${index.index+1}, listeHeures = ${heures} )}"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>




    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my dependecies

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>mereuta.marian</groupId>
<artifactId>tennis01</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tennis01</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3 -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>






    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add the appropriate `java8time` support from Thymeleaf to enable this properly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that will allow you to use the `temporals` as [noted in Github](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time).  To excerpt a relevant example from there:

```
${#temporals.format(temporal)}
```